# Merge several .ab1 sequence files into a single FASTA file?

Tags: bioinformatics

I have several .ab1 files generated from Chromas. I want to merge all of them into a single FASTA sequence file. How can I do this in an automated way?

Note that I don't have Chromas installed (the files were generated by someone else). I am using linux, so open-source, command line tools are preferred.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should use a [base calling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_calling) algorithm to generate the sequences from the chromatogram and not directly convert it to fasta ([*Courtesy: Sven [SEQanswers]*](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3165) ). As mentioned in the link, [phred](http://www.phrap.org/consed/consed.html#howToGet) and [TraceTuner](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tracetuner/) are popular base calling software that can generate a fasta output.

The software mentioned by *The Nightman* can be used for converting `.ab1` to fasta. You can also try this BioPython module called [abifpy](https://github.com/bow/abifpy). You can easily read each `.ab1` file, using a python script, and write the sequences in fasta format as a single file.

Combining multiple fasta is quite trivial. You can use `cat` as mentioned by others.

Answer (score 1):

DNA Baser has a batch abi to fasta converter [here](http://www.dnabaser.com/download/Abi-to-Fasta-converter/abi-to-fasta-converter.html). After files have been converted to .fa files, they can be concatenated together in UNIX/MAC using `cat *fa > output.fa`

Answer (score 1):

Typical possibilities that come to mind are programs available in [EMBOSS](http://emboss.open-bio.org/) and [Staden](http://staden.sourceforge.net/). However the question of how to access the sequence data stored in .ab1 files has been asked on Biostars a number of times, so I suggest having a look at the various answers there for options that are suitable for your environment and use case, see [Biostars search "ab1"](https://www.biostars.org/local/search/page/?q=ab1).